# How can I addition of 3 counts fields in MySQL one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 counts `count(like), COUNT(comment), COUNT(views),` what I want is to addition of this 3 in that query and get the total addition of this 3 counts.

Note:- I am using 3 joins for get this 3 count and group by for group by posts.

e.g. -

```
COUNT(like) = 5
COUNT(comment) = 3
COUNT(views) = 12
so i need a key total_count = 20
```

Is this possible?

```
SELECT up.id, COUNT(upl.id) as likes_count, COUNT(upc.id) as collected_count, COUNT(upvb.id) as viewed_by_count 
FROM posts as up 
LEFT JOIN post_likes as upl ON upl.post_id = up.id 
LEFT JOIN post_viewd_by as upvb ON upvb.post_id = up.id 
LEFT JOIN post_collected as upc ON upc.post_id = up.id WHERE up.status = 'Active' GROUP BY up.id 
ORDER BY likes_count DESC, up.insertdate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT up.id, COUNT(upl.id) as likes_count, COUNT(upc.id) as collected_count, COUNT(upvb.id) as viewed_by_count , COUNT(upl.id)+COUNT(upc.id)+COUNT(upvb.id) AS Total 
 FROM posts as up 
 LEFT JOIN post_likes as upl ON upl.post_id = up.id 
 LEFT JOIN post_viewd_by as upvb ON upvb.post_id = up.id 
 LEFT JOIN post_collected as upc ON upc.post_id = up.id 
 WHERE up.status = 'Active' 
 GROUP BY up.id 
 ORDER BY likes_count DESC, up.insertdate DESC
```

Comment: I tried it before, not giving any error but also not giving key `Total`.

Comment: I tested the query in my database with `Join` ,`group by` and `order by`  and it works and gives key `Total`

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your result?

Comment: Thank you, it is working, i make a small mistake while checking result, it is coming properly.

Comment: @Sahil . . . I don't understand why you accepted this answer.  The counts should not be correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you want correct counts, then one method is correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT up.id,
       (likes_count + viewed_by_count + collected_count) as total
FROM (SELECT up.*,
             (SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM post_likes upl 
              WHERE upl.post_id = up.id
             ) as likes_count,
             (SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM post_viewd_by upvb 
              WHERE  upvb.post_id = up.id 
             ) as viewed_by_count,
             (SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM post_collected pc
              WHERE  pc.post_id = up.id 
             ) as collected_count
       FROM posts up 
       WHERE up.status = 'Active' 
      ) up
 ORDER BY likes_count DESC, up.insertdate DESC;
```

Assuming you have an index on the `post_id` in all the subsidiary tables, this should also be the fastest method.